# Serve Angular 2 project from static folder with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, angular, spring-security

So I have a working frontend with Angular2 and a working backend with Java and what I do is to serve my index.html from the static folder which also contains all my frontend resources. The problem is that when I tried to add Spring Security to the backend the resources are not accessible anymore because of the @EnableWebSecurity annotation. When I navigate to my localhost http://localhost:8080/ the index.html is not served. But if I access it or any other resource writing the path manually, it loads.
I wouldn't like to serve my frontend differently, is there any way to do this from the static? I tried the following:

Here my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ramso.restapi.security"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

public static final String REMEMBER_ME_KEY = "rememberme_key";

public SecurityConfig() {
    super();
    logger.info("loading SecurityConfig ................................................ ");
}

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;


@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/front/**","/index.html");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/failure").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
            .and();

}
}
```

WebMvcConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
//registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("front/index.html");
//registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/index.html");

registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}

}
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you can add the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/front/**");
}
```

Any ant matcher you put in `web.ignoring()` method should be ignored by spring security.

By default the static content should be placed in one of the following directories under `src/main/resources` (from [spring boot - static content](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)):

```
/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static/
/public/
```

Then any ant matcher is checked in front of the sub folders.

For example, if your static content is in `src/main/resources/static/front` the ant matcher `/front/**` should ignore all resources in that sub-folder.

Also, in order to expose `index.html` you should place it in `src/main/resources/static` and add something like the following class in order to expose it as the main resource when accessing your site:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

}
```

and of course add it as an ant matcher: `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*", "/front/**", "index.html");`

`/*` will not allow all, `/**` does that. make sure you place your API's on a secure endpoint like `/api` or something like that and the static content on an ignored path.

Comment: straight in static or in the folder front, src/main/resources/static/front?

Comment: I tried both, right now I have it in src/main/resources/static/front

Comment: Can you try to access a specific resource to see if the problem is with the ant matcher or exposing your index.html? If you have a problem exposing your index.html (assuming it is in the front folder) I can add the relevant code to expose it in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136182/discussion-between-tom-and-battalgazi).

Comment: Well the addViewControllers is somehow not doing what it should. The index.html is not being served when I start the program. But if I try to access resources manually they are accessible so the filter is working...

Comment: No I dont have @EnableWebMvc. I edited my post and added all my config files, maybe you can find something wrong there

Comment: I figured it out. you need to do the following: 1) change ignoring to: `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*", "/front/**", "index.html");` dont worry it will not allow all unless you do `"/**"`. 2) change in `WebMvcConfiguration` to `registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");`. 3) it will be better to change your `configureGlobal` to override `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` - its the default to set `UserDetailsService` - `auth.userDetailsService()` if you can

Comment: I created a fast test project with the configuration you provided and it works fine, do you have any other configuration you did not post?

Comment: I don't think that i have anything that may have any influence there... could u maybe send me somehow that test project so I can compare? Anyway im gonna review my whole code again

Comment: I tried your project, it works. Mine still doesn't and I have no idea why, looks the same. I don't have much time now but i'll rebuild it and come back again...

Comment: Ok, I found why: You wrote the following in your project: web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*", "/front/**", "index.html");  didnt we say that adding /* would activate all routes? isnt that what we dont want?

Comment: So I could finally make it work using the following atMatchers: web.ignoring().antMatchers("/", "/front/**", "index.html"); If I use "/" without the asterisk the html is being served and no other route is ignored. I consider the subject closed :) Thanks for your time and effort, just a little thing cost too much trouble. xD

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that angular-cli puts all resources at the root of your app. (Though I'm not sure you are using angular-cli)

But lets entertain the notion.

angular-cli outputs something like

```
/inline.8faab088ca0e1cca9031.bundle.js
/main.c7b67df9d7c42383815c.bundle.js
/polyfills.c234d2c8820869e3c698.bundle.js
/styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css
/vendor.f0f36dacdf3fba21c295.bundle.js
```

This makes it very hard for you to apply a spring security antMatcher.

angular-cli has a configuration called `--deploy-url=/ui/` which will mean that all script files point to a directory called `/ui/`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/inline.4c30f42211c1d30d3dd3.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/polyfills.c234d2c8820869e3c698.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/vendor.f0f36dacdf3fba21c295.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/main.c7b67df9d7c42383815c.bundle.js"></script>
```

Then you should be able to ignore the path as Tom suggests.

Comment: Im not using angular cli